# Some companies asks you to mail them for a job, what exactly you should mention in the email?

Tags: job-search, email

There are some companies which mentions things like "If you think you have got what it takes...." send us an email at xxx for job.

I googled to look for a template to understand what things people include in such emails but unfortunately it showing templates for job where you ask someone for a referral, could you please share what to write in such emails or point me to a resource?

Comment: There is no generic answer to that. Some companies will expect a full cover letter (aka job application letter) in email, while others consider a short _"Yo, I'm interested in a role as <xyz>, here is my CV"_ is sufficient. Though usually it is a safer bet to take the first route than the second.

Comment: They don't have job role mentioned on site but something like if you have skills and would like to be part of the company send us an email at xxx

Comment: @Jack, In your CV/resume, you can either totally skip the reference section (if you don't have a good reference) or try to get a reference from your former teachers, bosses, etc... Many companies don't even ask candidates to list the references on the resumes. Good luck.

Comment: It completely depends on the job itself. Is this for a marketing job or a copywriting job? or some other type of job?

Answer (score 4):

You should:

1. Mention the exact role you are applying for (or, if there is no particular role listed, what kind of role you want)
2. Attach a resume/CV/LinkedIn profile link/portfolio/whatever is customary for your industry and location
3. Have the body of the email be what used to be called a “cover letter” but not a huge and detailed one at this point - just explain in brief why you think you are a great fit for the position they have open
4. Contact information for yourself, preferably a phone number

They will contact you with more guidance if that basic payload interests them.

Answer (score 2):

Example,

> The android layout job for a sports app looks FANTASTIC. I am particularly expert with advanced android layout issues - the most complex custom views, single blah apps, animations. I've worked in the Sports field many times before and am very familiar with it. Please see my resume and contact me on 2556666969 or fattie@fat.com.

I have followed @mxyzpik.  Note that (3) has two parts:

1. Mention the role you want
2. Attach a pdf resume
3. State

- A. Your *technical* expertise to the role *(be technically specific)*
- B. Your *field* experience to the role

4. Give phone number

### What's this about 3A and 3B?

Regarding 3A and 3B, some examples:

- It's a web app for stock brokers.  (A) You mention your relevant specific kickass skills ("I'm a leading AJAX expert"). (B) You mention your *field* experience ("I worked for both Bernard Madoff and Ivan Boesky").
- It's a back end for travel.  (A) You mention your relevant specific kickass skills ("I've built many systems both sql and nosql"). (B) You mention your *field* experience ("I built the API for both an airline and a travel agent.").

### What is the secret sauce to aceing these emails?

**3A and 3B are the secret**. If you do that, you will get past the email every time. Don't tell anyone else the secret.